# Is PostgreSQL's EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM <interval>) 1-based?

Tags: sql, postgresql, intervals

Consider the following query:

```sql
SELECT 
  INTERVAL '1 month' * v AS i, 
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM INTERVAL '1 month' * v) AS y, 
  EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM INTERVAL '1 month' * v) AS q, 
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM INTERVAL '1 month' * v) AS m
FROM generate_series(0, 16) t(v)
```

It yields, to my surprise:

```
i            |y|q|m |
-------------|-|-|--|
     00:00:00|0|1| 0|
        1 mon|0|1| 1|
       2 mons|0|1| 2|
       3 mons|0|2| 3|
       4 mons|0|2| 4|
       5 mons|0|2| 5|
       6 mons|0|3| 6|
       7 mons|0|3| 7|
       8 mons|0|3| 8|
       9 mons|0|4| 9|
      10 mons|0|4|10|
      11 mons|0|4|11|
       1 year|1|1| 0|
 1 year 1 mon|1|1| 1|
1 year 2 mons|1|1| 2|
1 year 3 mons|1|2| 3|
1 year 4 mons|1|2| 4|
```

So, when extracting a `QUARTER` from such a "normalized" `INTERVAL` (produced by an `INTERVAL '1 month' * <some integer>` expression), we get values `1-4` (as if this extraction were somehow 1-based), whereas extracting a `YEAR` or `MONTH` from an `INTERVAL` produces values `0-N` (`YEAR`) or `0-11` (`MONTH`), respectively.

What's the rationale behind this behaviour and is it documented? ([I do not think it is documented here, explicitly](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html))

Comment: So, further down the page (following section link to 9.9.1 from the extract function) where it says "The quarter of the year (1 - 4) that the date is in" isn't sufficient documentation?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: That applies to extracting `QUARTER` from a `TIMESTAMP`, not an `INTERVAL`. Likewise, extracting a `MONTH` from a `TIMESTAMP` yields values `1-12` for good reasons, whereas extracting `MONTH` from an `INTERVAL` as shown above yields values `0-11`, also for good reasons.

Comment: The start of section 9.9.1 states "The extract function retrieves subfields such as year or hour from date/time values. source must be a value expression of type timestamp, time, or interval. " and is the section entitled `EXTRACT(field FROM source)`. Why do you not think it applies to interval?

Comment: And the `month` documentation separately states what happens for timestamp vs interval, for example.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Yes, it does that for `MONTH`, not the rest (e.g. not for `YEAR`, either). But omission of documentation is not per se documentation. I'm just observing behaviour, and would like to know if this is safe to use.

Comment: The rationale behind it is that Quarter is a Business Term, existing well before the development of electronic computers. Try this, go tell your VP of Finance the their quarterly reports are not rational, they should refer to Q0, Q1, Q2, and Q3. *See how far the gets you.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is.

You seem to be going out of your way to avoid a plain reading of the documentation. Section 9.1.1 starts:

> 9.9.1. EXTRACT, date_part
>
> ```
> EXTRACT(field FROM source)
> ```
>
> The extract function retrieves subfields such as year or hour from date/time values. source must be a value expression of type timestamp, time, or *interval*. ... The following are valid field names

(My *emphasis*)

It then goes on to describe each field and the values that are possible. Absent any indicators to the contrary, then, this is documentation for what happens when extracting fields from an interval.

And, indeed we see for example `day`:

> For `timestamp` values, the day (of the month) field (1 - 31) ; for `interval` values, the number of days

So, we can see that, where they wish to highlight a difference between interval and timestamp, they can do it in individual field descriptions. Similarly for `month` they separately document timestamp and interval handling, so they seem to have a *consistent* way of documenting differences.

So, finally, we get to `quarter`:

> The quarter of the year (1 - 4) that the date is in

That's it. That is the documentation, and it applies equally to timestamps and intervals.

Comment: Well, I agree with much of this, but it does say "that the *date* is in", which does not follow the consistency. Combined with what I believe is inconsistent *behaviour*, I wonder if this is really intended. Anyway. I believe we both got each other's points...